# Restrict field types to have only objects that implement interface

Tags: java, classloader

I am writing a system that can save states of a generic DataModel (object tree) to provide functionalities like restoring old states and providing workcopies that can commit and pull changes to achieve thread safety on the DataModel. In order to do so, all complex objects (no primitive wrapper classes or null) must extend a DataModelEntity interface, that provides basic functionality for parsing and deparsing an objects state.

By generic DataModel I mean that the specific Classes of the Model are not known to the system, only that they extend the DataModelEntity interface.

I want to restrict all classes in that DataModel to only have primitives, primititve Wrappers, null or **other classes extending DataModelEntity** as fields. Fields of objects that are no DataModelEntity should be illegal.
Is their any way to enforce such a restriction on all classes extending my DataModelEntity interface?

Comment: There's no standard way to do that compile-time, as far as I know. However, you could use reflection to check whether classes fulfill this requirement at runtime.

Comment: Problem with that is that I can't enforce that whatever method doing this checking with reflections is called, so I can not guarante that this condition is truly enforced on the classes. Maybe one can do this at a more depper level with a custom class loader?

Comment: I don't think writing a custom class loader solves the problem you're facing. Their primary job is to *load* classes into memory from a resource, not *restrict* classes from having certain fields. Furthermore, if you can't enforce the method doing this checking to be called, you also cannot enforce which classloader loads the class.